# The type or namespace name 'UserRoleLevelDetails' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, session, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to use one method for storing and get list of object in session and use it in `.cshtml` file. For that I have given below code.

```
@inject IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor;
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
@inject IConfiguration Configuration
@model IEnumerable<TCS.ConfigDomainModel.UserManagement.UserRoleLevelDetails>
@using ConfigWeb.Helpers

@HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetObjectFromJson<UserRoleLevelDetails>("GetAllUsersList")
```

But when i use this I'm getting this error:

> Cannot convert method group 'GetObjectFromJson' to non-delegate type 'object'. Did you intend to invoke the method?

So I changed this from:

```
@HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetObjectFromJson<UserRoleLevelDetails>("GetAllUsersList")
```

To

```
@(HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetObjectFromJson<UserRoleLevelDetails>("GetAllUsersList"))
```

Now I'm getting below error:

> Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'UserRoleLevelDetails' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Can anyone help on this?

I'm using below SessionHelper class

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace MMWeb.Helpers
{
public static class SessionHelper
{
    public static void SetObjectAsJson(this ISession session, string key, object value)
    {
        session.SetString(key, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value));
    }

    public static IList<T> GetObjectFromJson<T>(this ISession session, string key)
    {
        var value = session.GetString(key);
        return value == null ? default(IList<T>) : JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<T>>(value);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try typing the full path to the object.

change

```
@(HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetObjectFromJson<UserRoleLevelDetails>("GetAllUsersList"))
```

to

```
@(HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetObjectFromJson<TCS.ConfigDomainModel.UserManagement.UserRoleLevelDetails>("GetAllUsersList"))
```

Comment: Did the solution work?